# Link Google Login with a StackExchange id?

Tags: feature-request, login

I use google login to logon stack overflow. But google has been blocked by Chinese government for a long time so it is a little bit difficult to login using google now.

It seems that I could add more logins there, but there is no stackexchange. Is there any way that I could link my account with a new stackexchange id so I could use it to login?
[image: Use different logins]

Comment: Maybe related/helpful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159786/does-add-more-logins-not-work-or-is-it-misleading

Comment: I assume you have to do this from the SE Network profile page? http://stackexchange.com/users/login?noauto=true

Comment: Yes, social networks and email services are likely to be blocked. So I'm trying to find a way where I could link my current account (logged in using google) to a stack exchange id. In that case, I can use stackexchange id/passwd to login to my account. @rene